# onLocationChanged does not get called when app is closed

Tags: android, locationmanager

i have been searching the internet for answeres for this problem but so far nothing worked for me. 
Im trying to get location updates in the background. When "onLocationChanged" gets called a check method is started which then will or will not send a notification. The problem is onLocationChanged doesn't seem to get called at all when i close my application. The only time that onLocationChanged gets called is when i reopen my app. I want my application to constantly check for location changes.

Thats the code im using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
private Location location;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createData();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
   .......
}

@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
      if(newactiveplace(location))
          sendnotification();
}
```

Can anyone pls. help?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Use location service to do that stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override what happens when the user closes the activity. Use:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   startActivity(i);
   //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

That way when the user presses the back button, it will leave the app in the background and you will still have your services running.

Watch out because with the location updates you will be draining the user's battery and probably the user won't even know that the app is running.

Comment: great thanks a lot it really seems to work now. im surprised that onBackPressed() doesnt seem to be mentioned anywhere. I am also concerned about the users battery though... i might need to adjust the params for requestLocationUpdates

Comment: Glad to help :) Remember to verify the answer for other users if it worked!

Also know that as I said, this not an "ideal" situation, so maybe warn users somewhere (maybe an ongoing notification) that the app will be updating the location on background.

Comment: do you know a better way to do it?

Comment: Nope, as far as I know, that's it